# Can't get div to stick to bottom of another div with position: absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a div to stick to the bottom of another div using `position: absolute` and `bottom:0; right:0`, but it isn't working because there's still a small space left between the div and the bottom.

```css
#weekly-product-container {
  margin-top: 91px;
  background: black;
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#triangle5 {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-left:  300px solid transparent;    
  border-bottom:  200px solid red;      
  border-bottom-right-radius: none; 
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="weekly-product-container">
  <div id="triangle5"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do, is add **position: relative**; to weekly-product-container and change **bottom: 0;** for triangle5:

```
#weekly-product-container {
    position: relative;
}

#triangle5 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/cr29y1tc/30/

Comment: Tried it, that puts `#triangle5` in the top corner.

Answer (score 1):

Set `position: relative;` on container:

```css
#weekly-product-container {
  margin-top: 91px;
  background: black;
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
#triangle5 {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-left:  300px solid transparent;    
  border-bottom:  200px solid red;      
  border-bottom-right-radius: none; 
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="weekly-product-container">
  <div id="triangle5"></div>
</div>
```